# DAU/MAU Google data studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I am trying to plot DAU/MAU in google data studio but when I try to create a formula it always says invalid formula.

Additionally, if I try to insert a scorecard with DAU it always fails.

Please advice.

Comment: Please provide an example of your failing formula for us to look at. Thanks. (You always need to ask the question with sufficient information for us to help you move forward with your problem. See the StackOverflow 'tour' or help text.)

Comment: You may for example have what GDS sees as 'bad' usage of dimensions and metrics - GDS is really awkward on some of this stuff.

Comment: @MandyShaw, the root cause of the issue seems to be with the 1 day and 7 day active users, when I try to create a scorecard chart with metric as 1 day active users it fails with the following error:
"The dimensions and metrics selected for this chart can't be displayed together. Try changing the fields.

Error ID: fefe2fca"

The same happens with 7 and 28 day active users, however if I try and create a trend line as a time series graph it works.

With the formula I am trying : 1 Day Active Users / 28 Day Active Users and the error when I click on save is invalid formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you may be coming up against the fact that GA data does not present to GDS as a single data set with all columns in, but rather as different purpose subsets which can't all be joined together. What you *could* do (as recommended by my son who does this stuff on a daily basis) would be to use the GA plugin in Google Sheets, use formulas there to get the data as you want it, and then point GDS at your Google Sheet data.

Answer (score 1):

To create a scorecard for daily or monthly actives:

Click the pencil next to the metric and make sure it's set to Sum

[image]

Set the default date range to Custom and set the interval to Yesterday.

[image]

You might also find [this article](https://www.evanbarale.com/guides/2018/8/26/automated-dailymonthly-active-user-stats-in-google-data-studio) interesting. It shows how to use Google Sheets to combine the DAU / MAU stats.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the below query on the data studio when you link among firebase, bigquery, and data studio;

```
SELECT
      (
      SELECT  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as count
      FROM   `projectName.events_*` AS A
      
      WHERE   A._TABLE_SUFFIX = CONCAT( SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS string), 0 , 4), 
                                        SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS string), 6 , 2), 
                                        SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS string), 9 , 2))
      
      AND     PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) = DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      )AS DAU,
    
      (
      SELECT  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as count
      
      FROM   `projectName.events_*` AS A
      
      WHERE   A._TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN CONCAT( SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AS string), 0 , 4), 
                                              SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AS string), 6 , 2), 
                                              SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AS string), 9 , 2)) 
                              AND     CONCAT( SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS string), 0 , 4), 
                                              SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS string), 6 , 2), 
                                              SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS string), 9 , 2))
      
      AND     PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
                                               AND     DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      )AS WAU,
      
      (
      SELECT  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as count
      
      FROM   `projectName.events_*` AS A
      
      WHERE   A._TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN CONCAT( SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS string), 0 , 4), 
                                              SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS string), 6 , 2), 
                                              SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS string), 9 , 2)) 
                              AND     CONCAT( SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS string), 0 , 4), 
                                              SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS string), 6 , 2), 
                                              SUBSTR(CAST(DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS string), 9 , 2))
      
      AND     PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
                                               AND     DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      )AS MAU
```